# Zero data when php data type is int

Tags: php, function, class, oop, variables

I wrote a function that takes the screen resolution and performs mathematical operations with PHP.

```
namespace example\standart;

class calc
{
    public $width, $height;

    function __construct(){
        $this->width = "<script>document.write(screen.width)</script>";
        $this->height = "<script>document.write(screen.height)</script>";
    }

    function findPerc($per)
    {
        $per = $per / 100;
        return $per * intval($this->width);
    }

    function findPercHeight($per)
    {
        $per = $per / 100;
        return $per * intval($this->height);
    }
}
```

Then I included my class on the page as you see below:

```
$calc = new example\standart\calc();
```

When I directly press the width value to the screen, I successfully see the result.

```
echo $calc->width;
```

But when I run my findPerc() function, I get 0 response. This is because of the intval() function. When I convert String data type to int data type with any function, I get 0 result. How can i solve this problem?

Thanks you.

Comment: You convert the string in `$this->width` to integer, but since it does not start with a number, it will result in `0`. As Andru S. said below, you cannot expect Javascript code to execute, it works fundamentally different (you need to send stuff from the browser to a script via a HTTP request)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your __construct() function you literally assign strings to $this->width and $this->height. These strings are just strings (although you expect them to run as JS code).

You can't get screen dimensions this way.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).